# Multiple URLs Single Server

Tags: domain-name-system

In the DNS I have setup multiple URLs for my website (all pointing to same server). The entries in DNS looks like as below:

### Host            TTL     Numeric IP

www   .mysite.net   7200        192.168.31.12

@ (None)   .mysite.net  7200        192.168.31.12

mycompany     .mysite.net   7200        192.168.31.12

I wrote a code on Login.aspx page to check the URL and navigate to appropriate company login page. So if I type www.mysite.net or mysite.net then I am getting navigated to standard login page. But when I type mycompany.mysite.net still I am getting navigated to standard login page. But when I type https://mycompany.mysite.net then I am getting navigated to company specific login page. Why I need to type complete URL with https to get navigated to compay specific login page? Why it is not working just with mycompany.mysite.net? Any help of this is highly appriciated.

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Can you provide some information about your server setup? Type of http server? Does the https instance have the same docroot/etc as the http instance?

Comment: We are using IIS 6.0 and installed wildcard server certificates for SSL. Login.aspx is the default page for the site which checks the URL and based on that navigates to company specific login page withing the same virtual directory. Do let me know if you need any other information.

Answer (score 1):

The normal way to accomplish this is by letting your server software inspect the host headers and use the right website directory based on them. Search for IIS Host Header or Apache Virtual Host for more information on how to accomplish this.

Your current problem lies in your script which you didn't share, so we can't debug it, you should print out the two values you are comparing to see what's going wrong.

Comment: I am using IIS 6.0. I only have one web site and not two. Still do we need to configure IIS Host Header?

Comment: Sorry for this somewhat late response as I haven't checked ServerFault since... Look, if you want your code to handle showing the login page then this question should be moved to StackOverflow, in the other case you could solve this by multiple web sites for each login page and thus configure the Host Headers. A singe web page doesn't necessarily need host headers.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the HTTP server will handle this so you don't have to write the code to do this.  It is called virtual hosts, and in particular, in this case, name based virtual hosts.

Comment: Hi, Can you please give me some more information on this? I am got bit stuck on this. I am using IIS 6.0.